# navigator.geolocation issues (Show the Local Weather FCC)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make the "Show the Local Weather" exercise from FreeCodeCamp but i'm having some issues with the JS part.

Sometimes when I click the button, it shows the Name and the temperature from lat = 35 and lon = 139.
And sometimes it shows my city name and temperature.

Why it doesnt always show my city name and temp?

https://codepen.io/rvprado/pen/QrxjWK
JS CODE:

```
var api = "https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/";
var lat = 35;
var lon = 139;

var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
};

function success(pos) {
  var crd = pos.coords;
  lat = crd.latitude;
  lon = crd.longitude;
};

function error(err) {
  $("#error").html('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#getMessage").on("click", function(){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success,     error, options);

  //Print the lat + lon to check
  $(".message").html(lat+ " " + lon);

  //Forming the API link
  api = "https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon;   

  // Printing API to check  
  $(".message").html(api);
  $.getJSON(api, function(json){
        $(".message").html(json.name + " " +json.main.temp + "ºC");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `getCurrentPosition()` is asynchronous. You can't use `lat` & `lon` until it has completed (in the success callback)

Comment: How do I do that @charlietfl ?

Answer (score 0):

Since `getCurrentPosition()` is asynchronous, There's a chance it won't happen immediately, So we need to wait for it because we're relying on the latitude,longitude properties.

One of solving this, is to move the API call to the success callback.

```
function success(pos) {
    var crd = pos.coords;
    lat = crd.latitude;
    lon = crd.longitude;
    api = "https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon;  
    $.getJSON(api, function(json) {
      $(".message").html(json.name + " " + json.main.temp + "ºC");
    });
}
```

Now we are guaranteed that the api call will happen after we get latitude and longitude.

Comment: Dit it but still got the other city information as well.

Comment: Did exactly that but shows the location of the other city.
Could you test on my pen?
https://codepen.io/rvprado/pen/QrxjWK
If I click a lot i still get information for the default lat/long of 35/139.

Comment: huh? it works fine. try `console.log(json);` and see what it has, keep in mind that accuracy of the location won't be 100%.